# How to Convert IEnumerable<T> to ConcurrentBag<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

My linq query returns a collection of `IEnumerable<object>`.

How can I convert this into a strongly typed object of collection `ConcurrentBag<object>` ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`ConcurrentBag` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381771.aspx) that takes an `IEnumerable`.

```
IEnumerable<T> myEnum = ...
ConcurrentBag<T> myBag = new ConcurrentBag<T>(myEnum);
```

Answer (score 18):

You could use the [proper constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381771.aspx).

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = ...
ConcurrentBag<Foo> concurrentFoos = new ConcurrentBag<Foo>(foos);
```

Answer (score 11):

`ConcurrentBag<T>` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381771.aspx) that takes an `IEnumberable<T>` as input.

Several collections support this, so make sure to check the constructor overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the extension method:

```
public static ConcurrentBag<T> ToConcurrentBag<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) => new ConcurrentBag<T>(source);
```